# Running shell script from java and capturing return value

Tags: java

I a trying to run a shell script from java and want to capture the exit value from shell script in java.
Below are the codes that I have tried along with their outputs

**Java Code 1:**

```
try {
            

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "dir //pathOfSHFile//Test.sh");
                Process proc = processBuilder.start();
                proc.waitFor();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                String output = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                 output += line;
                } 
                System.out.println("### " + output);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**Test.sh file**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "good"
```

**Output 1:**

```
###  Volume in drive C is OSDisk Volume Serial Number is *** Directory of C:\Data\Code07-12-2020  12:10                22 Test.sh
```

Was expecting "good" as the output.

**Java code 2:**

```
try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"C:\\Data\\Code", ".\\Test.sh"});

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Output 2:**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Data\Code": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:486)
    at Intersecttion.main(Intersecttion.java:53)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 3 more
```

I tried to give permission to all the folders but still same result.
I need to pass one argument as well to the script but not sure how to get that done and run the script as well and get exit value.
Is there any better way to do this apart from above ones.

Comment: I don't really remember how exactly it works on Windows, but shouldn't you run the script-runner like [`cmd.exe`, `/c`, _path to the script runner executable_, _path to the script_]? (I mean, no space-combined arguments, no spaces in between like in your #1, `dir` is a cmd-builtin, Windows is not aware of shebangs, `C:\Data\Code` may be a directory, etc etc etc.)

Comment: Yes, i was trying to test and run this on windows. I am trying to put the code on linux and test whether it works or not

Comment: No, that is what i was missing and i think in the first output it was just returning the last folder which i have mentioned instead of running Test.sh file.

Comment: Java 7 added method [redirectOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.io.File)) to class `ProcessBuilder`. There is also method `redirectError`. Is that not what you are looking for? or perhaps method [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) is appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2 tries to execute the folder. This should work:

```
        String path = "C:\\Data\\Code";
        String command = path + "\\Test.bat"; // Test.sh renamed
//      String command = "bash Test.sh"; // bash execution when installed on Windows
        
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        
        Process pr = rt.exec(command, null, new File(path));

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

However, you may have to change your script to a batch file "Test.bat" instead as Windows will not natively execute shell scripts. You can also install bash and execute the `bash` command with the script as a parameter. I added that as a commented line.

Comment: The OP is asking for a Unix(-like) shell script execution issue, not a Windows batch file. Renaming the script file is definitely not a solution as it requires porting the script to Windows.

Comment: Where do you read that it has to be Unix-like? echo "good" may as well be part of a batch file. The problem I understood here was that whatever was to be executed, was not properly executed from Java.

Comment: 1) The question title clearly says "shell" script, whilst Windows uses "batch file" terminology since the DOS times. 2) The code snippet demonstrates a shell script source code. 3) Both Java snippets attempt to run `test.sh`. 4) I don't think that the OP would raise a question just for running a single `echo` externally.

Comment: Still I think the problem displayed in both versions above were not raised by executing a shell script, but by executing a command in the wrong location.

Comment: I'm not at a Windows machine right now, but what would happen if not renaming the file but having `bash` installed on Windows? Would Windows associate the `sh` file extension to `bash` so that it would do the job?

Comment: No, not directly. If you use the windows subsystem for linux (e.g., with the Ubuntu app), you will have to execute the bash command. I updated the answer.

Comment: @achim- The above code works on windows machine but since i need to run a shell script from windows and that was not happening because of bash not being installed on the path. I tried the same code on Linux and that worked.

Comment: if you really need to execute a Linux shell script you need the bash command. For example, you can activate the windows subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) and the Ubuntu app through the Microsoft store. Then you can call bash as mentioned above in the commeted line.